# Pdf download in React.js project

Tags: reactjs, charts, pdf-generation

I am building my project in React.js where I have added several graphs and I want to download the Graph data in PDF format on click of a button. With graph data I would also want to have graph images, but this is my secondary requirement.
Can anyone help me with this. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you could approach this, the easier way I think is you could do it on the client side using a library such as html2pdf. The other way is you could do it on the backend using a server side library. I recently did something similar and I ended up doing it on the client side using this library https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/ and it was pretty easy to implement.